# Java - Timer Delay between actions

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

I have a (probably stupid) Question...
I've been trying for hours to program a timer that pauses between commands, but I can't get it to work. It should look like a kind of "slot machine" effect. Have already tried a few things and am desperate. Could someone please help me or at least give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Window implements ActionListener
{
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    JFrame MAIN = new JFrame("Test");
    Integer[] ZufallsNUMBERen = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    String[] Names = { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4" };
    JButton B_Start = new JButton();
    Integer NUMBER = 0;
    Timer timer;

    JLabel Name1 = new JLabel(Names[0]);
    JLabel Name2 = new JLabel(Names[1]);
    JLabel Name3 = new JLabel(Names[2]);
    JLabel Name4 = new JLabel(Names[3]);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Window().window();

    }

    public void window()
    {
        MAIN.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MAIN.setLayout(null);
        MAIN.setResizable(false);
        MAIN.setSize( 665, 519);
        MAIN.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        MAIN.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#008080"));
        MAIN.setVisible(true);
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - MAIN.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - MAIN.getHeight()) / 2 - 100);
        MAIN.setLocation(x,y);

        B_Start.setBounds(250, 110, 300, 300);


        Name1.setBounds(100,125,200,40);
        Name2.setBounds(100,200,200,40);
        Name3.setBounds(100,275,200,40);
        Name4.setBounds(100,350,200,40);
        Name1.setFont(new Font("SnowCaps", Font.BOLD, 30)); 
        Name2.setFont(new Font("SnowCaps", Font.BOLD, 30)); 
        Name3.setFont(new Font("SnowCaps", Font.BOLD, 30)); 
        Name4.setFont(new Font("SnowCaps", Font.BOLD, 30)); 


        MAIN.add(B_Start);
        MAIN.add(Name1);
        MAIN.add(Name2);
        MAIN.add(Name3);
        MAIN.add(Name4);

        B_Start.addActionListener(this);

        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    NUMBER = NUMBER +1;

                    Slot1();
                    System.out.println(NUMBER);

                    Slot2();
                    System.out.println(NUMBER);

                    Slot3();
                    System.out.println(NUMBER);

                    Slot4();
                    System.out.println(NUMBER);
            }
        });
    }
    public void Slot1(){
        Name1.setText(Names[0]);
        Name2.setText(Names[1]);
        Name3.setText(Names[2]);
        Name4.setText(Names[3]);

        NUMBER = NUMBER +1;
    }
    public void Slot2() {
        Name1.setText(Names[3]);
        Name2.setText(Names[0]);
        Name3.setText(Names[1]);
        Name4.setText(Names[2]);

        NUMBER = NUMBER +1;
    }
    public void Slot3() {
        Name1.setText(Names[2]);
        Name2.setText(Names[3]);
        Name3.setText(Names[0]);
        Name4.setText(Names[1]);

        NUMBER = NUMBER +1;
    }
    public void Slot4() {
        Name1.setText(Names[1]);
        Name2.setText(Names[2]);
        Name3.setText(Names[3]);
        Name4.setText(Names[0]);

        NUMBER = NUMBER +1;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == B_Start)
        {
            if(!timer.isRunning())
                timer.start();
            else
                timer.stop();
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Variable names and method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. Any text book or tutorial you use will follow these standards.

Answer (score 2):

Use NUMBER (or another iterator variable) to break up the timing of your Slot method calls.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                NUMBER = NUMBER +1;

                If (NUMBER.intValue() == 1) {
                  Slot1();
                  System.out.println(NUMBER);
                }
                If (NUMBER.intValue() == 2) {
                  Slot2();
                  System.out.println(NUMBER);
                }   
                ...
        }
```